# How to prevent a page from being popped?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I prevent a Stateless widget (a page) from being popped? I have a button click that pops the stack. This is for deep navigation, you can keep clicking the button until it brings you back to the first page. However you can also pop the first page, How to prevent this?

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Comment: I don't think i understand exactly what you want to achieve, put there's a widget called WillPopScope that you can wrap your page and controll the moment that your page will pop and allow it or not

Comment: I believe this only prevents the System from stopping the pop. I am still able to pop the last page on the stack using the Navigator.

Comment: Hum, i just got it what you want. You can use canPop from navigator to check if the page is the last one on the stack

Comment: @RodrigoBastos
Sweet this is what I needed. Helped me clean up a lot of weird logic I had implemented. Submit this as official answer and I will select it.

Comment: Great that worked man. Select as accepted answer so it can help more people!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your the page that you don't want popped in WillPopScore and it allows you to call a function before popping. If the function returns false, it won't pop, so you can perform any logic you may want to verify that the page should be discarded.

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: //Your page
),
```